# Possible to request and store entire url

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I would like to store entire url in a variable and insert into a data extension. I know you can grab specific parameters from a url but cant seem to find anything about the entire url with ampscript.

My url looks like this and i want to capture and store the whole thing

https://fe3e15707564057a7d1470.pub.s10.sfmc-content.com/tfuryofct5y?optc=%%=v(@optc)=%%&ceid=%%=v(@ceid)=%%

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what querystring parameters you're going to receive ahead of time? If so, you can probably do this:

> SET @StoredURL = CloudPagesURL(URL_ID,'optc',@optc,'ceid',@ceid)
>   InsertDE('Your_DE','URL',@StoredURL)